# Receive and process a SOAP message

Tags: python, soap, python-3.4, bottle, suds

Got a service provider (Safaricom) that has decided to use SOAP to send mobile money payment notifications to businesses. When the mobile user pays (either through USSD or via a web interface) the mobile money service will send a SOAP message that we are supposed to consume.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:c2b="http://cps.huawei.com/cpsinterface/c2bpayment"> 
<soapenv:Header/> 
<soapenv:Body> 
    <c2b:C2BPaymentValidationRequest>
        <TransactionType>PayBill</TransactionType> 
        <TransID>1234560000007031</TransID> 
        <TransTime>20140227082020</TransTime> 
        <TransAmount>123.00</TransAmount> 
        <BusinessShortCode>12345</BusinessShortCode>
        <BillRefNumber></BillRefNumber> 
        <InvoiceNumber></InvoiceNumber> 
        <MSISDN>254722703614</MSISDN> 
        <KYCInfo> 
            <KYCName>[Personal Details][First Name]</KYCName> 
            <KYCValue>Hoiyor</KYCValue> 
        </KYCInfo> 
        <KYCInfo> 
            <KYCName>[Personal Details][Middle Name]</KYCName> 
            <KYCValue>G</KYCValue> 
        </KYCInfo> 
        <KYCInfo> 
            <KYCName>[Personal Details][Last Name]</KYCName> 
            <KYCValue>Chen</KYCValue> 
        </KYCInfo> 
    </c2b:C2BPaymentValidationRequest> 
</soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>
```

*Don't worry the above details are public information*

Question is, using a framework like bottle (or even Django) how do I "accept" this message and how do I extract the details from within the message.

I've used `suds-jurko` to consume Soap Services but I've  never been on the receiving end of a SOAP call.

At minimum though am able to get the message using `payment_data = request.body.read()`

```
from bottle import request
payment_data = request.body.read()
print(payment_data)
```

From there though I've tried using XML parsers in python but its getting  complicated. Is there a way for suds (or [zeep](http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/latest/index.html#)) to allow me to get the data from the xml object?

Answer (score 0):

I hope it's not late for an answer:
For the C2B transactions there is a project on github https://github.com/kn9ts/project-mulla it takes the request from the checkout in POST form, converts it to a SOAP request, send it to safaricom, receives the response from safaricom and gives a response in Json format.